# Help Understanding/Completing Supremum Proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $s\in \mathbb{R}$ have the property that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $s+\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for $A$ and $s-\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $A$. Show that $s=$ sup $A$.

I know there is an answer to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760078/help-with-real-analysis-proof-involving-supremum) however I am having trouble following the proof.

Here is what I have so far based on my knowledge and the answer I am trying to understand:

In order to show $s=$ sup $A$ we need to show first that $s$ is an upper bound for A. **Claim**: s is an upper bound. This would imply that $\forall a \in A$, $s\geq a$. Suppose $s>a$. We are given that $s+\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$ ($\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$) is an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

If a set of real numbers $A$ is bounded from above, then it has a least upper bound.  Since $s+1/n$ is an upper bound, the supremum of $A$ is not greater than $s+1/n$.  But we also know that $s - 1/n$ is not an upper bound for $A$.  So it's supremum must be at least as large as $s-1/n$.  Now can consider the closed intervals $[s-1/n, s + 1/n]$.  This collection of sets has the property that any finite number of them has non-empty intersection.  In particular this intersection contains $s$.  Since the collection of sets is nested, the infinite intersection is not empty.  But it can contain only one point, namely $s$.  That point is the lowest possible upper bound for $A$.  So it is $sup A$.

Comment: does the infinite intersection only contain the one point $s=$ sup $A$ due to the proof for the Nested Interval Property?