# Analysis proof involving bounded intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

This proof is somewhat similar to the question asked here: [Help with real analysis proof involving supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760078/help-with-real-analysis-proof-involving-supremum). But it's the other way around.

Question: Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of the real numbers, bounded above. Show that if $u = sup S$, then for every natural number $n$, the number $u − 1/n$ is not an upper bound of $S$, but the number $u + 1/n$ is an upper bound of S.

Here is my approach.
First, I write the conditions for my proof to satisfy. They are, for every natural number $n$ the following two must satisfy,

$$
(I)\hspace{1cm} s\leq u+1/n,\forall s\in S \\
(II)\hspace{1cm}\exists s \in S \ni s\geq u-1/n
$$

Now we prove this by induction. First, we have to establish the base case for $n=1$.

We can easily show that, when $n=1$

$u+1/n = u+1$

Since $u+1>u$, it is clearly an upper bound for $S$. (I) holds.

and
$u-1/n = u-1$.

since $u-1 < u$, it is clearly not an upper bound for $S$. Which means (II) holds.

$\\\\\\$

Now let's assume that the conditions (I) and (II) are true for some integer $m$.

i.e:

$ s\leq u+1/m,\forall s\in S$ and

$\exists s \in S \ni s\geq u-1/m$

but the case $m+1$ implies, $u+1/m > u+1/(m+1)$

It can be proven using the following process.

$u+1/m > u+1/(m+1) \Leftrightarrow 1/m > 1/(m+1) \Leftrightarrow m+1 > m \Leftrightarrow 1>0 $

Now the problem is this does not guarantee $ s\leq u+1/(m+1),\forall s\in S$.

Note that $u+1/(m+1)$ fall between $u$ and $u+1/m$.

The same is true for $u-1/(m+1)$ situation.

Any insights into this would be appreciated.

Comment: The definition of least upper bound is that anything smaller than it is not an upper bound.  So nothing smaller then $u$ can be an upper bound.  Period.  And the concept of upper bound is that it is as large or as large as every element.  So anything larger than an upper bound will also be an upper bound.  Period.  So $u -\frac 1n < u < u+\frac 1n$.  So if $u = \sup S$ then anything smaller than $u$ is not an upper bound and everything bigger than $u$ is an upper bound.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: You have fallen into the trap that everything in analysis has to be difficult. That's a myth. A lot of analysis textbooks have gone to great lengths to turn trivial facts into complicated high brow stuff. Remember that by the very definition every number greater than supremum is an upper bound and every number less than supremum is not an upper bound. And it should be quite obvious that $u-1/n<u<u+1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supremum means the least upper bound. You are given that u is the least upper bound of the set S. $u+1/n>u$ for all natural numbers $n$ since $1/n>0$. So, it is greater than the least upper bound, meaning it is an upper bound.
Similarly, $u-1/n<u$ since $1/n<0$ for all natural numbers $n$. Since it is smaller than the least upper bound, it is not an upper bound.

Comment: Does it not require an inductive proof?

Comment: I don't think so. Please ask if you have doubts about the explanation I provided.

Comment: Your argument seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $T$ be the set of all upper bounds for $S.$ By definition, $u=\sup S$ is the least member of $T.$ If $n\in \Bbb N$ then $u-1/n<u.$ So if $u-1/n$ were an upper bound for $S$ then $u-1/n$ would be a member of $T$ that's less than the least member ($u$) of $T$, which is absurd.
2. By definition of $T,$  we have, for any $v,v',$ that $$v'>v\in T \implies \forall s\in S\,(v'>v\ge s)$$ $$ \implies \forall s\in S\,(v'\ge s)$$ $$\implies v'\in T.$$ In particular $n\in \Bbb N\implies u+1/n>u\in T\implies u+1/n\in T.$

Answer (score 2):

Note:  $u - \frac 1n < u = \sup S$.  And note that $u + \frac 1n > u = \sup S$.

That is *IT*!  You are done.

The *definintion* of $u = \sup S$ is:

1. $u\ge x$ for all $x \in S$.

So $u+ \frac 1n > u \ge x$ for all $x \in S$.  So $u+\frac 1n$ is an upper bound.  That's all there is to it.

2. If $w < u$ then $w$ is *not* an upper bound of $S$.

So $u-\frac 1n < u$.  So $u-\frac 1n$ is not an upper bound of $S$.   End of story.